Proving Conditional Likelihood Of Samples Factorizes to Product of Conditional Marginals
One of my test questions was to prove that given that the samples $(x_i, y_i)$ are independent of each other then the conditional likelihood
$p(y_1, ..., y_N | x_1, ..., x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^{N}{p(y_i|x_i)}$, my idea was to say that
$p(y_1, x_1, ..., y_N, x_N) = \prod_{i}{p(y_i, x_i)} = \prod_{i}{p(y_i|x_i) * p(x_i)}$
so that $p(y_1, ..., y_N | x_1, ..., x_N) = \frac{\prod_{i}{p(y_i|x_i) * p(x_i)}}{p(x_1, ..., x_N)}$
For the denominator to cancel it would require that $p(x_1, .., x_N) = \prod_{i}{p(x_i)}$
if my approach was correct can someone explain if this holds: $p(x_1, .., x_N) = \prod_{i}{p(x_i)}$
If not can you help me explaining the correct approach please.

Hello everyone i asked my professor he said it does hold because, $p(x1, .., x_N) = \prod_{i}{\int{p(x_i, y_i)dy_i}}=\prod_{i}{p(x_i)}$
